# implement builder method to serialize json

Tags: java, class, serialization, jackson, builder

I need help. I am trying to implement  the following class

```
Relationship usesRel = Relationship.builder()
            .relationshipType("uses")
            .created(Instant.now())
            .build();
```

this is my RelationShip class

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Relationship.Builder.class)
public class Relationship {
    
    private String relationshipType;
    private String description;
    private DomainObject sourceRef;
    private DomainObject targetRef;
    
    private Relationship(String relationshipType,   String description, DomainObject sourceRef, DomainObject targetRef) {
        this.relationshipType=relationshipType;
        this.description=description;
        this.sourceRef=sourceRef;
        this.targetRef=targetRef;
        
    }
    
    @JsonPOJOBuilder
    public static class Builder{
        String relationshipType1;
        String description;
        DomainObject sourceRef;
        DomainObject targetRef;
        
        Builder setRelationshipType (String relationshipType) {
            this.relationshipType1 = relationshipType;
            return this;
        }
        
        Builder setDescription (String description) {
            this.description = description;
            return this;
        }
        
        Builder setSourceRef (DomainObject sourceRef) {
            this.sourceRef = sourceRef;
            return this;
        }
        
        Builder setTargetRef (DomainObject targetRef) {
            this.targetRef = targetRef;
            return this;
        }
        
        public Relationship build() {
            return new Relationship(relationshipType1,description,sourceRef,targetRef);
        }
    }

}
```

My question is how do I create the .builder() method.

or could someone point me to a documentation where I could learn how to implement

Answer (score 0):

You're already 90% of the way there.

Your `builder()` method simply creates a new `Builder` and returns it:

```
public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for  you quick answer
I changed the class Relationship adding at the end 
`
public static Builder builder() {
     return new Builder();
 }
`
it shows the following error 
Cannot reference a field before it is defined

Comment: sorry is because is static it has to go first because in java static objects arre executed in order of declaration :{

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there are two reload methods:

```
public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
}

public static Builder builder(String relationshipType, String description, DomainObject sourceRef, DomainObject targetRef) {
    return new Builder (relationshipType, description, sourceRef, targetRef);
}
```

Also, don't forget to add an empty private constructor, it's good practice:

```
private Builder(){

}
```

And you can named this method more luckily, for example `init()`